# Setting a time on Wifi hotspot

Tags: wifi-hotspot

Does anyone have an approach to automatic disabling the wifi hotspot? I was working at home last night, forgot to switch it off, and ended up downloading 3GB over my 4G connection. Thankfully, I have plenty of spare, but... could have been pricey.

I'm thinking I'll stick with USB for now, but I'm thinking either a timeout on the hotspot (and I don't mind the "annoyance" of having to refresh every half hour), or maybe something that switches it off when I'm at home and connected to my own wifi network (like, something that can say "hey, network xyz is here, so I'll disable hotspot").

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm)(Paid) or [condi](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=il.co.kix.minitasker)(Free) , there is similar question to this one [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/125592/is-there-a-way-to-automatically-turn-off-the-wireless-hotspot-once-i-get-back-ho)